# Sticky sidebar active 120px from the top

Tags: jquery, sidebar, sticky

I have a this code which creates the sticky side bar when the #sidebar div reaches the top of the page, however I want the sticky sidebar to activate when it is 120px from the top rather than when it reachers the top of the page, because it goes under my header then reaches the top and slides down, any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance

```js
var $sidebar = $("#sidebar"),
  $window = $(window),
  offset = $sidebar.offset(),
  topPadding = 0;

$window.scroll(function() {
  if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
    $sidebar.stop().animate({
      marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
    });
  } else {
    $sidebar.stop().animate({
      marginTop: 0
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #000;
}
.left {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 600px;
  float: left;
}
.right {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: green;
  height: 600px;
  float: left;
}
.topblock {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}
#sidebar {
  background-color: #efefef;
}
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid: z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="left">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="topblock"></div>
    <div id="sidebar">
      <p>SIDEBAR</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rdt0so9/)

Comment: A jsfiddle would be helpful

Comment: Hi Lian, here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8rdt0so9/  hope that is ok, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to consider the height of your header:

Instead of this: `if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top)`

do this:
`if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top - headersize)`

Updated your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8rdt0so9/3/

```js
var $sidebar = $("#sidebar"),
  $window = $(window),
  offset = $sidebar.offset(),
  topPadding = 70;

var headersize = $('.header').height();

$window.scroll(function() {
  // show some live info
  $('.header').html(
    'window.scrollTop(): ' + $window.scrollTop() + "<br/>" +
    'offset.top: ' + offset.top + "<br/>" +
    'headersize: ' + headersize
  );
  if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top - headersize) {
    $sidebar.stop().animate({
      marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
    });
  } else {
    $sidebar.stop().animate({
      marginTop: 0
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #000;
}
.left {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 600px;
  float: left;
}
.right {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: green;
  height: 600px;
  float: left;
}
.topblock {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}
#sidebar {
  background-color: #efefef;
}
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid: z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="left">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="topblock"></div>
    <div id="sidebar">
      <p>SIDEBAR</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That has worked perfectly thank you very much, I tried everything, i'm a bit of a jQuery novice :) one last question, if say I wanted to add and extra 10/20px to the header size so it activated before it went under the header, would that be hard?

Comment: @BenMillar, you only need to minus that in your condition. `if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top - headersize - 10)`

Answer (score 0):

When enough browsers support it, you will be able to use the new [`sticky` positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning):

```css
#sidebar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px; /* header's height */
}
```

```css
#sidebar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px; /* header's height */
}
.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #000;
}
.left {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 600px;
  float: left;
}
.right {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: green;
  height: 600px;
  float: left;
}
.topblock {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}
#sidebar {
  background-color: #efefef;
}
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid: z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="left">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="topblock"></div>
    <div id="sidebar">
      <p>SIDEBAR</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```